# LESS: Cannot find mixin

Tags: less

Okay so I've been using the BEM method since recently.

There's just one thing, this works:

```
.font--fa {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    text-rendering: auto;
}

.some-random-class {
    .font--fa;
}
```

Whereas this doesn't work:

```
.font {
    &--fa {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        text-rendering: auto;
    }
}

.some-random-class {
    .font--fa;
}
```

It says cannot find mixing .font--fa.

I would like to be able to do this, is it possible at all in less?

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1624

Comment: In other words: update your Less tools.